# Android calendar view set colors with no deprecated methods

Tags: java, android, xml, calendarview

In my android project I have calendarView on white background,I just want to set all dates in calendar to black but can't find how.

Answer (score 1):

In style.xml use this

```
   <style name="BlueCalenderView" >
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/desired_color</item>
    </style>
```

If you want to change color of days

```
 <style name="CalenderViewDateCustomText" parent="android:TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/desired_color</item>
    </style>
```

If you want to change color of weeks

```
<style name="CalenderViewWeekCustomText" parent="android:TextAppearance.DeviceDefault.Small">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/desired_color</item>
    </style>
```

Finally, in your layout:

```
 <CalendarView
            android:id="@+id/calendar"
            android:theme="@style/BlueCalenderView"
            android:weekDayTextAppearance="@style/CalenderViewWeekCustomText" 
            android:dateTextAppearance="@style/CalenderViewDateCustomText"
            ..... />
```